# Why VS2017 folders are named 15 and 15.0_e7be0fe2?

Tags: visual-studio-2017

this doesnt make any sense.
Why VS2017 folders are named 15 and 15.0_e7be0fe2 ??

c:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0\
c:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_e7be0fe2\
c:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\NestingProfiles\
c:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages\
c:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\SettingsLogs\
c:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\vshub\

They couldnt come up with a better more descriptive name than "15.0_e7be0fe2"?

And why does it start with 15? I have only installed VS2017.

What is "15" folder for?

Why have these 2 folders with such weird names?

Doesnt make any sense.

Comment: 15 is not a year, it is the version number.  14 was VS2015, they skipped 13.  The unlucky coincidence at VS2010 is not easily forgotten.  VS2017 was completely re-engineered to support agile development.  Any 15.x.0 release is very buggy, typically 7 more updates are need to make it stable again.  Repeats again at x+1, x=8 today.  Isolating data from a previous release that is not backwards compatible, using a wonky directory name like "15.0_e7be0fe2", was intentional.

Comment: Thanks Hans, I wonder often - what do they smoke there to overcomplicate and confuse everyone with all these numbers.. ;)

Comment: It is a sensible scheme.  You are not supposed to have to worry about it, hard to tell why you do.